# How do I collect unique elements of an array-valued field across multiple objects in jq?

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I have json data that looks like:

```
{"foo":"one", "bar":2, "baz":[0]}
{"foo":"two", "bar":3, "baz":[1]}
{"foo":"one", "bar":3, "baz":[2,3]}
{"foo":"one", "bar":2, "baz":[2,4]}
```

I want to group everything with the same "foo" and collect the unique values of bar, and then collect the unique values inside of the "baz" arrays:

```
[
  {"foo":"one", "bar":[2, 3], "baz":[0,2,3,4]},
  {"foo":"two", "bar":[3], "baz":[1]}
]
```

(I don't care if the result is in an array or just a raw sequence of whitespace separated JSON objects, and I don't care about the order of the items in the "baz" array)

I've got jq version 1.4 installed from source.  I can properly group by "foo" and collect unique values of "bar" with:

```
jq -s 'group_by(.foo) | map({foo: .[0].foo, bar: map(.bar) | unique})'
```

yielding:

```
[
  {"foo":"one","bar":[2,3]},
  {"foo":"two","bar":[3]}
]
```

but I can't figure out how to do the collection of unique values of "baz".

What am I missing?

Answer (score 15):

**Edit**: new "[flatten](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#flattenflattendepth)" function not needed (thanks
 @JeffMercado)

I can run

```
jq -s 'group_by(.foo) | map({foo: .[0].foo, bar: map(.bar) | unique, baz: map(.baz) | add | unique})
```

which produces:

```
[
  {"foo":"one","bar":[2,3],"baz":[0,2,3,4]},
  {"foo":"two","bar":[3],"baz":[1]}
]
```

Comment: You could have just used `add`

Comment: @JeffMercado Do you have an example of how to do it that way?

Comment: Just replace `flatten` with `add`. Fortunately, all baz values are arrays so adding the arrays together has the same effect.