# How do I group values to an array for the same field value in jq?

Tags: arrays, json, group-by, jq

I have json data that looks like

```
[
  {
    "session": "ffe887f3f150",
    "src_ip": "81.71.87.156"
  },
  {
    "session": "fff42102e329",
    "src_ip": "143.198.224.52"
  },
  {
    "session": "fff9c8ca82be",
    "src_ip": "159.203.97.7"
  }
]
```

I've managed to filter out unique values of `session` but there can be more `sessions` linked to a same `src_ip`.

Now I would like to merge the dataset in a way so that I have grouped `session` ID's to `src_ip` at one place such as

```
[
...
  {
    "src_ip": "81.71.87.156"
    "sessions": ["ffe887f3f150","fff42102e329"]
  },
...
]
```

This is somewhat similar to question asked here: [How do I collect unique elements of an array-valued field across multiple objects in jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26128753/how-do-i-collect-unique-elements-of-an-array-valued-field-across-multiple-object) , however I struggle to transform that for my scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `group_by` you can group by any criteria given, then assemble all grouped items by taking their common `.src_ip` from any of them (eg. the first), and `.sessions` as a mapped array on `.session` from all of them. Add other parts as you see fit.

```sh
jq 'group_by(.src_ip) | map({src_ip: .[0].src_ip, sessions: map(.session)})'
```