# jq get unique value from two keys

Tags: json, unique, jq

I know to get a unique from one key - `unique_by('.[].name)`

I want to get output by checking for unique values in two keys

but how to do for two keys like `unique_by('.[].name,.[].url')`  and return the input along with other keys?

#input

```
[
  {
    "name": "abc",
    "url": "https://aa.com",
    "created_at": "2022-09-30T11:17:33.181Z"
  },
  {
    "name": "bb",
    "url": "https://ddd.com",
    "created_at": "2022-09-30T11:14:33.180Z"
  },
  {
    "name": "abc",
    "url": "https://aa.com",
    "created_at": "2022-09-30T11:14:33.180Z"
  }
]
```

#expected output

```
[
  {
    "name": "abc",
    "url": "https://aa.com",
    "created_at": "2022-09-30T11:17:33.181Z"
  },
  {
    "name": "bb",
    "url": "https://ddd.com",
    "created_at": "2022-09-30T11:14:33.180Z"
  }
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I collect unique elements of an array-valued field across multiple objects in jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26128753/how-do-i-collect-unique-elements-of-an-array-valued-field-across-multiple-object)

Comment: what iis the difference between: `unique_by([.name, .url])` and `unique_by(.name, .url)`?  The output when trying both seems the same...

Comment: @Luuk Nothing. `unique_by` is [defined](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L8) using `group_by`, which in turn [collects](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L6) everything into an array anyway. It's just more readable providing the array oneself, as the usage without array is counterintuitive wrt other functions when provided with a stream in one argument.

Comment: @pmf: OK, I am more experienced in SQL than in JSON, and using SQL you would specify two values... 

Comment: Keep in mind that `,` separates items of a stream, not arguments in a function call. (In accordance to that, `[…, …, …]` is a stream of items collected into an array.) When providing multiple arguments to a function, you'd separate them with `;`, but `unique_by` (or to be explicit: `unique_by/1`) only accepts one argument, so `[.name, .url]` as well as `.name, .url` are both just a single (compound, structured, iterable, higher-rank, …) argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just provide to `unique_by` an array with everything included, so that the array must become unique:

```bash
jq 'unique_by([.name, .url])'
```

```json
[
  {
    "name": "abc",
    "url": "https://aa.com",
    "created_at": "2022-09-30T11:17:33.181Z"
  },
  {
    "name": "bb",
    "url": "https://ddd.com",
    "created_at": "2022-09-30T11:14:33.180Z"
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/M-FQMAGp4iO)

Answer (score 3):

Collect the criteria into an array:

```
unique_by([.name, .url])
```